Open VLC in full screen from .desktop file?
I'm using Pi OS (Bookworm 12 I believe) on a Pi4 and I'm trying to get VLC to startup into full-screen from a .desktop file. I've got it working, its launching the camera livestream as intended. I just need to get it into fullscreen without any interaction.
Here's the current file:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=vlc rtsp://ipcamera.address 

Is there a parameter I can add after the camera address to get VLC to launch into fullscreen? Or do I need a different solution?

Open a terminal and enter vlc --longhelp --advanced for a complete list of available options. Exec=vlc -f rtsp://ipcamera.address should do it. If this works for you let me know in a comment. I will turn this comment to an answer for you to accept as the correct answer.
